# PerlPod - Links don't seem to work

Tags: perl, perldoc

I have the following line in my POD documentation:

```
This is taken by the L<< Promoted Build
Plugin|https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin
>> C<$PROMOTED_JOB_NAME> environment variable.
```

I want this to format as:

```
This is taken by the 
<a href="https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin">
Promoted Builds Plugin</a> <code>$PROMOTED_JOB_NAME</code>
environment variable.
```

However, when I run `pod2html`, I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/pod2html: jdescribe.pl: cannot resolve 
L<Promoted Build Plugin|https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin>
 in paragraph 46.
```

According to the [Perlpod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html#Formatting-Codes) documentation and the [Perlpodspec](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpodspec.html#About-L%3c...%3e-Codes) documentation, this should be correct. Or, at least it looks that way to me.

What am I doing wrong?

By the way, the links do work with `pod2markdown`.

Comment: What does `podchecker` make of it?

Comment: What happens if you convert the `"+"`s to `"%2B"`?

Comment: @Zaid Podchecker is okay, and changing `+` to `%28` doesn't do a thing. It also dumps its cookies on `L<david@weintraub.name|mailto:david@weintraub.name>`. Again `pod2markdown` is fine with both.

Comment: your pod2html is probably too old, try `perl -MPod::Simple::HTML -e Pod::Simple::HTML::go Thing.pod Thing.html`

Answer (score 3):

Like optional already assumed, your pod2html is too old. Things started to work at some point between perl 5.14.x and perl 5.16.x.

To explain this: in older days, the construct `L<text|href>` was forbidden. The reasoning for this was that a non-hypertext Pod renderer (e.g. pod2text) would lose information if only the link text was displayed. This prohibition was removed in perlpodspec.pod with this commit:

```
commit f6e963e4dd62b8e3c01b31f4a4dd57e47e104997
Author: Ricardo Signes <rjbs@cpan.org>
Date:   Mon Dec 7 18:19:28 2009 -0500

    remove prohibition against L<text|href>
```

Nowadays, pod2text displays such a link as `text <href>`. And pod2html is now also able to create a real link.

If you cannot switch to newer versions of pod2html, then you have to restrict to links without the text part, e.g. `L<http://wiki.jenkinsci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Foo+Bar>`.